# Proving sendership of transactions

Tags: signature, verification, message-signing, message-verification

Why does Bitcoin Core, on the message verification tab, say that verifying messages signed by Bitcoin addresses "only proves the signing party receives with the address, it cannot prove sendership of any transaction." Why? And is there a method of proving sendership in Bitcoin?

Comment: I can't find the word 'sendership' on google related to bitcoin, except this very post. I don't use Bitcoin Core and never saw the message. But I believe it means that proving a bitcoin was sent is only possible with the actual bitcoin transaction being confirmed on chain. As opposed to being the owner of a receiving address.

Comment: @OsiasJota See: [src/qt/forms/signverifymessagedialog.ui line #240](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c098a8aa0780009c11b66b1a5d488a928629ebf/src/qt/forms/signverifymessagedialog.ui#L240)

Comment: Reading the full message I am more sure of my speculation above, but not so sure as to turn it into a full answer, I'll wait for someone to confirm it.